# How to solve the ConstraintViolationException?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I got this Exception when I try to save some data in my CRM Webapplication (PrimeFaces):

```
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'prePersist'. Please refer to embedded ConstraintViolations for details.
```

The problem is I can't figure out what is the cause of this. The log stack strace doesn't include any helpful information at all sadly...

I have many breakpoints and also inserted this ValidatorFactory code lines, which I found here on StackOverflow into the Insert and Edit methods I have (these are in my AbstractFacade Class), but this ValidatorFactory is giving me 0 invalid entites before the actual saving method, so I'm still not wiser... :

```
    public T edit(T entity) {
        logger.info("oldVersion {0}", new Object[]{entity.getVersion()});

        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        javax.validation.Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(entity);
        if (constraintViolations.size() > 0 ) { 
           logger.error("Constraint Violations occurred.."); 
           for (ConstraintViolation<T> contraints : constraintViolations) {
                logger.error(contraints.getRootBeanClass().getSimpleName()+
                "." + contraints.getPropertyPath() + " " + contraints.getMessage());
            }        
            getEntityManager().persist(entity);              
        }

        try {
            entity = (T) getEntityManager().merge(entity);
        } catch (OptimisticLockException e) {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage("Somebody already modified these lines:" + entity.getClass());
            entity = find(entity.getId());
            refresh(entity);
        }

        return entity;
    }
```

The error comes after the `getEntityManager().merge(entity);` is called in the `edit()` method.

Has somebody any idea what to do now?

EDIT:

I'm using Netbeans, EclipseLink (JPA 2.1) and Glassfish.
Logs says: "Please refer to embedded ConstraintViolations for details."

Where exactly is this EMBEDDED ConstraintViolations? I don't see anything regarding this in the Glassfish log...

I also edited my persistence.xml:

```
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
<property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINEST"/>
```

But after restart and retest I still seeing only the same log entries, nothing more...

Comment: Increase the log verbosity for JPA ( and your JPA implementation : Hibernate probably), you may find useful things.

Comment: The message says: Please refer to embedded ConstraintViolations for details. Have you done that? I.e. inspect the content of the ConstraintViolationException to see what constraint violations have been found?

Comment: No, it's EclipseLink (JPA 2.1) actually

Comment: Well, I changed the log level in my persistence.xml to this: <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL"/> sadly I still don't see any plus informations at all. (using: NetBeans, Glassfish)

Comment: The details are inside the ConstraintViolationException object. Use your debugger to navigate to that exception by looking at the cause of the actual exception being thrown, and look at what it contains. https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintViolationException.html#getConstraintViolations--